# Using alias from header file in corresponding source file

Tags: c++

I just started learning more of c++ and am writing a small rendering engine as an example case study. As i started to implement more code I got annoyed by typing types like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>
```

over and over again. As most of you know already, this get's infinitely worse if you are looping over said vector

```
for (std::vector<std::vector<Tile>>::const_iterator layerRow = ...) {}
```

Since this is not just annoying but also very error prone, I looked into using typedefs and soon changed those into alias', following Scott Meyers advice in "More effective C++".
I got one problem now which I can't seem to wrap my head around. Given the following two files (corresponding header and source file):

map.h:

```
class Map
{
  public:
    using tileLayerVector_t = std::vector<std::vector<Tile>>;
    using rawDataLayerVector_t = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
    tileLayerVector_t getTileLayer(const std::string pLayerName) const;
    void generateTileMapLayer(const std::string pMapLayerName, const rawDataLayerVector_t pRawMapData, const std::shared_ptr<Texture> pTexture);
}
```

map.cpp:

```
#include <map.h>

tileLayerVector_t Map::getTileLayer(const std::string pLayerName) const
{
  return mapLayers.at(pLayerName);
}


void Map::generateTileMapLayer(const std::string pMapLayerName, const 
rawDataLayerVector_t pRawMapData, const std::shared_ptr<Texture> pTexture)
{
  int tileCount = 0;
  int xPos = 0;
  int yPos = 0;

  ...

  std::pair<std::string, tileLayerVector_t> tileLayer(pMapLayerName, tileMapLayer);
  mapLayers.insert(tileLayer);
}
```

Function generateTileMapLayer() compiles fine without a problem. As soon as I implement getTileLayer() the UI is giving me an error "identifier 'tileLayerVector_t' is undefined" and the compiler is giving me some weird error about a missing ";" somewhere. This compiler error vanishes if I put getTileLayer() in comments.
I don't understand why I can use the alias within the function generateTileMapLayer() as a type definition for the hash map, but cannot use it as a return type for getTileLayer(). I put Map::tileLayerVector_t as a return type and it works. Why does it work without the namespace within generateTileMapLayer() though?

Maybe someone can help me with this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I never had that problem with `typedef`

Comment: @Tim Randall i tried it with typedef's as well but it's the same problem

Comment: What's with the downvotes? Come on guys. It's a specific and well-described problem. Just because you know the answer already isn't a reason to downvote!

Comment: yeah about the downvotes. I submitted the answer and had two downvotes after 15 seconds...someone having fun with their mouse i guess xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class defines a scope. How you access something in a given scope depends on whether you are writing code that's inside or outside that scope.

So when you make the declaration `using tileLayerVector_t = ...;` *within* `class Map` you are providing an alias for a new type `Map::tileLayerVector`.

This is why your code *inside* the class can use the type without qualification, but code *outside* cannot.

You could move your using-declarations outside the class, but that would pollute the global namespace. A better solution, I think, would be to simply qualify the types where needed:

```
Map::tileLayerVector_t Map::getTileLayer(...) // must qualify type here
{
    tileLayerVector_t temp = ...; // inside a class method, no problem here
}
```

A more modern solution would be to use "type inference". I believe you need at least a C++11 compliant compiler to take advantage of this feature. My understanding is that the trailing return type allows the compiler to defer establishing the actual type until after the function signature has been generated, at which point the scope has been established.

```
auto Map::getTileLayer(...) -> tileLayerVector_t
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I was thinking that it could work inside the method because the method is within the namespace Map but the return parameter is not. I wasn't sure about it though. Thank you for helping me! :)

Comment: `auto Map::getTileLayer(...) -> tileLayerVector_t` also works, if you're so inclined.